# Why does converting from MyISAM to InnoDB takes forever?

Tags: mysql, performance

I wanted to convert a 700MB table from MyISAM to InnoDB with the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I am not sure why it took forever (It did not complete, I killed the query after an hour of waiting). I observed that my memory usage climbed to 60% and plateau off. I am suspecting that adjusting some parameter may help, but I wonder which one.

Comment: Define "forever". You write like it took a really long period of time, but not forever. It would be helpful to know if it did complete, how long it took.

Comment: @todda.speot.is: It did not complete. I killed the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it needs to basically create a new table, copy all the data, create new indexes, and drop the old table. Both storage engines have very different ways of storing data on disk, so the conversion is nothing simple.

You could try just dumping the table into SQL, edit the dump so that create table statement uses InnoDB instead of MyISAM, and upload it back. I think it could be a bit faster.

Also notice, that default values for InnoDB buffer pool in your `my.cnf` can be really low, resulting in InnoDB not getting nearly enough memory to work effectively.

Comment: My innodb_buffer_pool_size is 134MB. How much more do you think is sufficient?

Comment: For a 700MB table? At least 1GB ;) General rule here is: the more, the better.

Comment: You provided the reason why it takes so long. I waited patiently this time and it did complete in 1hr 25min. Not sure if it could be done any faster though.

Answer (score 4):

There is a [discussion of issues](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/converting-tables-to-innodb.html) regarding conversion to InnoDB in the MySQL docs.

Here are some highlights/quotes:

- If your table has unique constraints, then turn off unique checks
  first:

  ```
  SET unique_checks=0;
  ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE = InnoDB;    
  SET unique_checks=1;
  ```
- "To get better control over the insertion process, it might be good to
  insert big tables in pieces:"

  ```
  INSERT INTO newtable SELECT * FROM oldtable
  WHERE yourkey > something AND yourkey <= somethingelse;
  ```

  After all records have been inserted, you can rename the tables.
- "During the conversion of big tables, you should increase the size of
  the InnoDB buffer pool to reduce disk I/O."
- "Make sure that you do not fill up the tablespace: InnoDB tables
  require a lot more disk space than MyISAM tables. If an ALTER TABLE
  operation runs out of space, it starts a rollback, and that can take
  hours if it is disk-bound."

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I adopted points 1 and 3. But it still took me 1hr 25min for a 700MB table and a 200MB index. Not sure if this is as fast as I can get.